# Signaling game : response to zero-probability message

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

We have this signaling game :

- sender type $t$ is uniformly distributed among $[0, 1]$. She takes action A if $t < \phi$, B if $t > \phi$
- if receiver takes action A' when seeing A and B' when seeing B, it is optimal for sender not to deviate. If the receiver react in any other way, it is optimal to deviate. A' is optimal for receiver if $t < \phi$ and B' if $t > \phi$

So this is an equilibrium.

**What happens if $\phi = 1$ ?**

If $\phi = 1$, and sender always send A, and receiver A', everything stays OK.
Sender will not send B if she is sure receiver respond B'.
**But** is responding B' a credible threat as $P(t > 1) = 0$ ?

Comment: What does "credible threat" mean here? You don't seem to have defined any payout function for the game -- what is everyone's _goals_ here?

Comment: I can defined the game more precisely, but I wanted to stay general. When $t < \phi$, A' gives higher payoffs, and when $t > \phi$, B' gives higher payoff to receiver. I believe responding B' to B is not a credible threat if $P(t > \phi) = 0$.

Comment: x @Guilro: Your comment is just repeating what the question already says, so I am no closer to understanding what you mean by "credible threat".

Comment: Ok sorry. By credible threat, I mean the strategy profile played by receiver is supposed to be subgame perfect. Playing B' when $t < \phi$ $P(t > \phi) = 0$ is not the best strategy. So the same question could be : is this equilibrium a Perfect Equlibrium when $\phi = 0$ ?

Comment: @Guilro This game has no proper subgame, if you take account of the choice of nature.